# Include suggestion in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ide, autocomplete

In MSVS it's so easy to find the missing include with the IDE's help.

Is there such an option in Xcode too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppCode does that, but Xcode (currently, at 4.3.1) doesn't support it.